# SQL Entry and Exit points specific problem with query

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

Background: 
I have some instrument data which has hundreds of thousands of records. I've simplified this by taking time slices over a number minutes. The raw data will have a specific reading at a point in time eg 0.004, however as the time sliced data is now a rollup this now contains 3 readings Min/Max/Avg of the same reading over the time slice.

I'm trying to create entry and exit points on this data. The one problem I have spent a few days trying to solve is I don't want an exit point being on the same time slice as the entry point. It must have a later PKey.

For example, this is wrong as the first record enters and exits on the same PKey.
[image]

Looking at the data I would exit entry and exit points to be as follows

Enter 3550724 - Exit 3551615

Enter 3559070 - Exit 3571982

Enter 3575126 - Exit NULL

As follows

[image]

Please can someone help correct my query so exit points is always later than the entry point and not equal. If there is no exit point then show the entry but exit point will be null.

My current query:

```
declare @EntryMinS1 float = 0.00418848167539267;
declare @ExitMaxT1 float = 0.00429319371727749;
declare @MinPressure float = 209.424083769634;
declare @YearFrom int = 2017;

with cte2 AS 
 ( -- apply your logic to mark potential entry and exit rows
   SELECT *
     ,CASE WHEN [Pressure] >= @MinPressure and MinS1 <= @EntryMinS1 THEN pKey END AS possibleEntry 
     ,CASE WHEN [Pressure] >= @MinPressure and MaxT1 >= @ExitMaxT1 THEN pKey END AS possibleExit
   FROM dbo.tblTestIntrumentData
   where year([TimeSlice]) >= @YearFrom
 )
 , cte3 as
(
    select * 
    ,Max(possibleEntry) -- most recent possibleEntry
      Over (PARTITION BY [IntrumentId], [TestName]
            ORDER BY pKey
            ROWS Unbounded Preceding) AS lastEntry 

    from cte2
)
, cte4 as
(
    select *
    ,Max(possibleExit) -- most recent possibleExit
      Over (PARTITION BY [IntrumentId], [TestName]
            ORDER BY pKey
            ROWS BETWEEN Unbounded Preceding AND 1 Preceding) AS lastExit
    from cte3
)
,groupRows AS 
( -- mark rows from the 1st entry to the exit row
SELECT *
    -- if lastEntry <= lastExit we're after an exit and before an entry -> don't return this row
    ,CASE WHEN lastEntry <= lastExit THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS returnFlag
    -- assign the same group number to consecutive rows in group 
    ,Sum(CASE WHEN lastEntry <= lastExit THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    Over (PARTITION BY [IntrumentId], [TestName]
        ORDER BY pKey
        ROWS Unbounded Preceding) AS grp
FROM cte4
WHERE (possibleEntry IS NOT NULL OR possibleExit IS NOT NULL)
    AND lastEntry IS NOT NULL
)
,rowNum AS
 ( -- get the data from the first and last row of an entry/exit group
   SELECT *
     -- to get the values of the 1st row in a group
     ,Row_Number() Over (PARTITION BY [IntrumentId], [TestName], grp ORDER BY pKey) AS rn
     -- to get the values of the last row in a group
     ,Last_Value(possibleExit)
      Over (PARTITION BY [IntrumentId], [TestName], grp
            ORDER BY pKey
            ROWS BETWEEN Unbounded Preceding AND Unbounded Following) AS ExitTimestamp
     ,Last_Value(CASE WHEN possibleExit IS NOT NULL THEN PKey END)
      Over (PARTITION BY [IntrumentId], [TestName], returnFlag, grp
            ORDER BY pKey
            ROWS BETWEEN Unbounded Preceding AND Unbounded Following) AS ExitPKey
   FROM groupRows
   WHERE returnFlag = 1
 )
select * from rowNum
where IntrumentId = 'N-12892'
and TestName = 'T451'
and rn = 1
ORDER BY IntrumentId, TestName, PKey
```

CREATE TABLE with schema and data:

```
USE [dbTestData]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[tblTestIntrumentData]    Script Date: 10/04/2019 10:13:20 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblTestIntrumentData](
    [TimeSlice] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [IntrumentId] [varchar](7) NOT NULL,
    [TestName] [varchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [AvgT1] [float] NULL,
    [MinT1] [float] NULL,
    [MaxT1] [float] NULL,
    [AvgS1] [float] NULL,
    [MinS1] [float] NULL,
    [MaxS1] [float] NULL,
    [MaxT2] [float] NULL,
    [MaxS2] [float] NULL,
    [MinB1] [float] NULL,
    [Pressure] [float] NULL,
    [pKey] [bigint] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tblTestIntrumentData] ([TimeSlice], [IntrumentId], [TestName], [AvgT1], [MinT1], [MaxT1], [AvgS1], [MinS1], [MaxS1], [MaxT2], [MaxS2], [MinB1], [Pressure], [pKey]) VALUES (CAST(N'2018-11-03T09:55:26.7680000' AS DateTime2), N'N-12892', N'T451', 0.004, 0.004, 0.005, 0.004, 0.004, 0.005, 1.116, 2.36, 0.003, 13025.385, 3550724)
INSERT [dbo].[tblTestIntrumentData] ([TimeSlice], [IntrumentId], [TestName], [AvgT1], [MinT1], [MaxT1], [AvgS1], [MinS1], [MaxS1], [MaxT2], [MaxS2], [MinB1], [Pressure], [pKey]) VALUES (CAST(N'2018-11-04T04:00:26.7680000' AS DateTime2), N'N-12892', N'T451', 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.006, 2.629, 0.438, 0.001, 15149.751, 3571982)
INSERT [dbo].[tblTestIntrumentData] ([TimeSlice], [IntrumentId], [TestName], [AvgT1], [MinT1], [MaxT1], [AvgS1], [MinS1], [MaxS1], [MaxT2], [MaxS2], [MinB1], [Pressure], [pKey]) VALUES (CAST(N'2018-11-03T10:25:26.7680000' AS DateTime2), N'N-12892', N'T451', 0.006, 0.006, 0.006, 0.006, 0.006, 0.007, 0.209, 2.718, 0.017, 13562.116, 3555221)
INSERT [dbo].[tblTestIntrumentData] ([TimeSlice], [IntrumentId], [TestName], [AvgT1], [MinT1], [MaxT1], [AvgS1], [MinS1], [MaxS1], [MaxT2], [MaxS2], [MinB1], [Pressure], [pKey]) VALUES (CAST(N'2018-11-03T10:30:26.7680000' AS DateTime2), N'N-12892', N'T451', 0.006, 0.006, 0.006, 0.006, 0.006, 0.006, 0.487, 3.223, 0.002, 13607.694, 3555878)
INSERT [dbo].[tblTestIntrumentData] ([TimeSlice], [IntrumentId], [TestName], [AvgT1], [MinT1], [MaxT1], [AvgS1], [MinS1], [MaxS1], [MaxT2], [MaxS2], [MinB1], [Pressure], [pKey]) VALUES (CAST(N'2018-11-04T04:35:26.7680000' AS DateTime2), N'N-12892', N'T451', 0.004, 0.003, 0.004, 0.004, 0.003, 0.004, 5.202, 3.001, 0.001, 16065.146, 3577673)
INSERT [dbo].[tblTestIntrumentData] ([TimeSlice], [IntrumentId], [TestName], [AvgT1], [MinT1], [MaxT1], [AvgS1], [MinS1], [MaxS1], [MaxT2], [MaxS2], [MinB1], [Pressure], [pKey]) VALUES (CAST(N'2018-11-04T04:40:26.7680000' AS DateTime2), N'N-12892', N'T451', 0.004, 0.003, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 4.482, 2.902, 0.001, 16350.153, 3578519)
INSERT [dbo].[tblTestIntrumentData] ([TimeSlice], [IntrumentId], [TestName], [AvgT1], [MinT1], [MaxT1], [AvgS1], [MinS1], [MaxS1], [MaxT2], [MaxS2], [MinB1], [Pressure], [pKey]) VALUES (CAST(N'2018-11-03T10:10:26.7680000' AS DateTime2), N'N-12892', N'T451', 0.007, 0.007, 0.007, 0.007, 0.007, 0.007, 0.962, 0.275, 0.005, 13295.4, 3553139)
INSERT [dbo].[tblTestIntrumentData] ([TimeSlice], [IntrumentId], [TestName], [AvgT1], [MinT1], [MaxT1], [AvgS1], [MinS1], [MaxS1], [MaxT2], [MaxS2], [MinB1], [Pressure], [pKey]) VALUES (CAST(N'2018-11-03T10:45:26.7680000' AS DateTime2), N'N-12892', N'T451', 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.006, 4.498, 14.667, 0.004, 13854.237, 3558230)
INSERT [dbo].[tblTestIntrumentData] ([TimeSlice], [IntrumentId], [TestName], [AvgT1], [MinT1], [MaxT1], [AvgS1], [MinS1], [MaxS1], [MaxT2], [MaxS2], [MinB1], [Pressure], [pKey]) VALUES (CAST(N'2018-11-04T04:20:26.7680000' AS DateTime2), N'N-12892', N'T451', 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 0.005, 5.426, 9.98, 0.003, 15762.039, 3575126)
INSERT [dbo].[tblTestIntrumentData] ([TimeSlice], [IntrumentId], [TestName], [AvgT1], [MinT1], [MaxT1], [AvgS1], [MinS1], [MaxS1], [MaxT2], [MaxS2], [MinB1], [Pressure], [pKey]) VALUES (CAST(N'2018-11-03T10:05:26.7680000' AS DateTime2), N'N-12892', N'T451', 0.007, 0.007, 0.008, 0.008, 0.008, 0.008, 1.007, 0.524, 0.001, 13273.765, 3552443)
INSERT [dbo].[tblTestIntrumentData] ([TimeSlice], [IntrumentId], [TestName], [AvgT1], [MinT1], [MaxT1], [AvgS1], [MinS1], [MaxS1], [MaxT2], [MaxS2], [MinB1], [Pressure], [pKey]) VALUES (CAST(N'2018-11-03T10:15:26.7680000' AS DateTime2), N'N-12892', N'T451', 0.007, 0.006, 0.007, 0.007, 0.007, 0.007, 3.585, 0.725, 0.003, 13378.195, 3553832)
INSERT [dbo].[tblTestIntrumentData] ([TimeSlice], [IntrumentId], [TestName], [AvgT1], [MinT1], [MaxT1], [AvgS1], [MinS1], [MaxS1], [MaxT2], [MaxS2], [MinB1], [Pressure], [pKey]) VALUES (CAST(N'2018-11-03T10:50:26.7680000' AS DateTime2), N'N-12892', N'T451', 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 0.005, 5.779, 8.781, 0.003, 13900.076, 3559070)
INSERT [dbo].[tblTestIntrumentData] ([TimeSlice], [IntrumentId], [TestName], [AvgT1], [MinT1], [MaxT1], [AvgS1], [MinS1], [MaxS1], [MaxT2], [MaxS2], [MinB1], [Pressure], [pKey]) VALUES (CAST(N'2018-11-03T11:00:26.7680000' AS DateTime2), N'N-12892', N'T451', 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 2.537, 2.045, 0.088, 14061.833, 3560585)
INSERT [dbo].[tblTestIntrumentData] ([TimeSlice], [IntrumentId], [TestName], [AvgT1], [MinT1], [MaxT1], [AvgS1], [MinS1], [MaxS1], [MaxT2], [MaxS2], [MinB1], [Pressure], [pKey]) VALUES (CAST(N'2018-11-03T10:20:26.7680000' AS DateTime2), N'N-12892', N'T451', 0.007, 0.006, 0.007, 0.007, 0.007, 0.007, 3.608, 3.609, 0.023, 13490.572, 3554492)
INSERT [dbo].[tblTestIntrumentData] ([TimeSlice], [IntrumentId], [TestName], [AvgT1], [MinT1], [MaxT1], [AvgS1], [MinS1], [MaxS1], [MaxT2], [MaxS2], [MinB1], [Pressure], [pKey]) VALUES (CAST(N'2018-11-03T10:55:26.7680000' AS DateTime2), N'N-12892', N'T451', 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 1.39, 1.569, 0.001, 13951.427, 3559895)
INSERT [dbo].[tblTestIntrumentData] ([TimeSlice], [IntrumentId], [TestName], [AvgT1], [MinT1], [MaxT1], [AvgS1], [MinS1], [MaxS1], [MaxT2], [MaxS2], [MinB1], [Pressure], [pKey]) VALUES (CAST(N'2018-11-04T04:10:26.7680000' AS DateTime2), N'N-12892', N'T451', 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 1.141, 3.528, 0.002, 15257.154, 3573476)
INSERT [dbo].[tblTestIntrumentData] ([TimeSlice], [IntrumentId], [TestName], [AvgT1], [MinT1], [MaxT1], [AvgS1], [MinS1], [MaxS1], [MaxT2], [MaxS2], [MinB1], [Pressure], [pKey]) VALUES (CAST(N'2018-11-03T10:35:26.7680000' AS DateTime2), N'N-12892', N'T451', 0.006, 0.005, 0.006, 0.006, 0.006, 0.006, 0.352, 0.898, 0.002, 13649.856, 3556601)
INSERT [dbo].[tblTestIntrumentData] ([TimeSlice], [IntrumentId], [TestName], [AvgT1], [MinT1], [MaxT1], [AvgS1], [MinS1], [MaxS1], [MaxT2], [MaxS2], [MinB1], [Pressure], [pKey]) VALUES (CAST(N'2018-11-03T10:40:26.7680000' AS DateTime2), N'N-12892', N'T451', 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.006, 0.005, 0.006, 4.496, 0.835, 0.001, 13824.016, 3557420)
INSERT [dbo].[tblTestIntrumentData] ([TimeSlice], [IntrumentId], [TestName], [AvgT1], [MinT1], [MaxT1], [AvgS1], [MinS1], [MaxS1], [MaxT2], [MaxS2], [MinB1], [Pressure], [pKey]) VALUES (CAST(N'2018-11-04T04:30:26.7680000' AS DateTime2), N'N-12892', N'T451', 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 21.651, 2.161, 0.005, 15963.565, 3576818)
INSERT [dbo].[tblTestIntrumentData] ([TimeSlice], [IntrumentId], [TestName], [AvgT1], [MinT1], [MaxT1], [AvgS1], [MinS1], [MaxS1], [MaxT2], [MaxS2], [MinB1], [Pressure], [pKey]) VALUES (CAST(N'2018-11-03T10:00:26.7680000' AS DateTime2), N'N-12892', N'T451', 0.007, 0.005, 0.007, 0.007, 0.007, 0.007, 1.257, 0.301, 0.001, 13226.338, 3551615)
INSERT [dbo].[tblTestIntrumentData] ([TimeSlice], [IntrumentId], [TestName], [AvgT1], [MinT1], [MaxT1], [AvgS1], [MinS1], [MaxS1], [MaxT2], [MaxS2], [MinB1], [Pressure], [pKey]) VALUES (CAST(N'2018-11-04T03:55:26.7680000' AS DateTime2), N'N-12892', N'T451', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0.018, 0.009, 0.018, 14788.663, 3571283)
INSERT [dbo].[tblTestIntrumentData] ([TimeSlice], [IntrumentId], [TestName], [AvgT1], [MinT1], [MaxT1], [AvgS1], [MinS1], [MaxS1], [MaxT2], [MaxS2], [MinB1], [Pressure], [pKey]) VALUES (CAST(N'2018-11-04T04:05:26.7680000' AS DateTime2), N'N-12892', N'T451', 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 0.005, 2.333, 4.672, 0.001, 15172.775, 3572744)
INSERT [dbo].[tblTestIntrumentData] ([TimeSlice], [IntrumentId], [TestName], [AvgT1], [MinT1], [MaxT1], [AvgS1], [MinS1], [MaxS1], [MaxT2], [MaxS2], [MinB1], [Pressure], [pKey]) VALUES (CAST(N'2018-11-04T04:15:26.7680000' AS DateTime2), N'N-12892', N'T451', 0.004, 0.004, 0.005, 0.005, 0.004, 0.005, 4.181, 2.161, 0.018, 15366.178, 3574277)
INSERT [dbo].[tblTestIntrumentData] ([TimeSlice], [IntrumentId], [TestName], [AvgT1], [MinT1], [MaxT1], [AvgS1], [MinS1], [MaxS1], [MaxT2], [MaxS2], [MinB1], [Pressure], [pKey]) VALUES (CAST(N'2018-11-04T04:25:26.7680000' AS DateTime2), N'N-12892', N'T451', 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 0.004, 3.549, 3.854, 0.003, 15838.353, 3575948)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can be simplified a bit, but I'm a bit stuck trying to think outside of the box of my current solution to actually find a simplification. Anyway:

```
declare @EntryMinS1 float = 0.00418848167539267;
declare @ExitMaxT1 float = 0.00429319371727749;
declare @MinPressure float = 209.424083769634;
declare @YearFrom int = 2017;

with cte2 AS 
 ( -- apply your logic to mark potential entry and exit rows
   SELECT *
     ,CASE WHEN [Pressure] >= @MinPressure and MinS1 <= @EntryMinS1 THEN pKey END AS possibleEntry 
     ,CASE WHEN [Pressure] >= @MinPressure and MaxT1 >= @ExitMaxT1 THEN pKey END AS possibleExit
   FROM dbo.tblTestIntrumentData
   where year([TimeSlice]) >= @YearFrom
),
cteFindExit AS
(
select *, -- find the first entry with an exit after our entry
       (SELECT MIN(pkey) FROM cte2 findExit 
         WHERE findExit.possibleExit > entrance.possibleEntry
           AND findExit.IntrumentId = entrance.IntrumentId
           AND findExit.TestName = entrance.TestName
         ) findExit
  from cte2 entrance
),
cteFindEntry AS
(
SELECT *
       -- it's not an entry if 
     , IIF(possibleEntry IS NULL  -- isn't a possible entry
           OR findExit = LAG(findExit, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY IntrumentId, TestName ORDER BY pkey) -- or has the same exit as the previous record
           OR COALESCE(possibleExit, findExit) IS NULL, -- or doesn't have an exit at all
           0,
           1 -- yeah it's a starter all right
           ) AS starter
  FROM cteFindExit
)
SELECT * FROM cteFindEntry WHERE starter = 1
```

`possibleEntry` and `findExit` define the set. [Here's a working example on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=134f81a15d6ef3d43d8892b7d89cf7e8).

In `cteFindExit` I'm looking for the first entry that is a possible exit and occurs after the possible entry here. So for our starting rows, this will be the exit. Then in `cteFindEntry` I'm discarding all the rows that actually aren't first entries, and this happens when:

- either the record is not an entry at all
- or, for the ones that are, their exit (from the `cteFindExit`) is the same as their predecessor's (this applies in the second group from your screenshot)
- or, for the ones that don't have a possible exit different than themselves, the possible exit is set (this will apply in the third group, when the exit truly is NULL, and will find the first record from that group)

Comment: Excellent thank you for you help. I have found that this also creates a problem where it also enters on the same pKey as an exit which I don't want. However, adding the following also solves this `...OR pKey = LAG(findExit, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY MarketId, RunnerName ORDER BY pkey)`. Thank you once again for making this easy to follow.